# Reading User Environment Variables into a Batch File

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have an app that's in C# that sets user environment variables

`PCManufacturer` and `PCModel`

I need to be able to read the values from the variables in a batch file. How do I do this?

I have tried `%PCManufacturer%` and `%PCModel%` but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to a command prompt and execute the SET command.  Verify that PCManufacturer and PCModel are in the list, and that they are set to actual values.

Comment: Yes There In List

PCManufacturer=Acer
PCModel=TravelMate 2480

Comment: Do I Have To Run "SET" B4 I can use the %PCModel% & %PCManufacturer%?

Comment: OK, now run the following command:

"ECHO %PCModel%"

It should have replied with 

"TravelMate 2480"

Comment: Ok Its Working Now How Do I Compare Them?

IF %PCModel%==Dimension 2400 ECHO Using A Dell

is that right?

Comment: If the string you are comparing has a space in it, you must surround it with quotes.  IF %PCModel%=="Dimension 2400" ECHO "Using A Dell"

Comment: Robert Harvey: In that case you also need to surround the %PCModel% with quotes. Also the quotes for echo are unnecessary and get output as well. Echo is a shell-builtin and doesn't follow the rules for C programs.

Answer (score 1):

c_workman:

As a follow-up, this web page should prove valuable:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true